# How to refresh the content when accessing Google drive with SAF

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm trying to access PDF files from Google drive within my app with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
```

which was taken from Google's documentation directly. I'm able to get the file picker to appear.  However there are 2 problems:

1. There is no way to refresh the content of the file picker.
2. Files newly added to the Google drive account will not appear until I go to the actual Google drive app and perform a refresh there.

I'm wondering if there is something missing in my implementation. I tried to search the web and surprisingly found nothing relevant. More surprisingly I got the same problem with the gmail app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Sorry David but no. In fact I filed a log with Android back in June ([Issue 211953](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211953)), but the status is still "New"...

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but it seems that it should be possible calling notifyChange with the URI of the path you want to update, see this https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-documentsprovider-f7f2fb38e86a#.953sim73z

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the info, and please do let me know if there is any success.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but from the link you provided it seems that notifyChange() is used within a DocumentProvider.  In my case I'm not writing a new one, but trying to use the Google Drive's DocumentProvider.  Therefore isn't it that notifyChange() should be called in Google's code instead of mine?

Comment: Update - got a new issue number: [Issue 37102575](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37102575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage access framework does invoke callbacks on active/selected provider (queryDocument and queryChildDocuments). It is up to the Google drive document provider to sync and notify SAF. SAF even supports streaming files of a large size. The sync logic itself is implementation logic dependent on doze mode etc.

In worst case, users can always pull down to refresh on the documents viewer to trigger the same callbacks.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-a-documentsprovider-f7f2fb38e86a.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm pretty sure swipe down was not available back in 2016 when the question was asked.  It is nice this issue finally got addressed.